# Simplistic Way to Execute One Function (Which Contains setInterval) Before Another Function

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have three functions and I want to execute one after another. my three functions are  `A_rray()`, `Counter()`, `Main_Function(N,A)`, I have condition for `Main_Function(N,A)` based on `A_rray()`, once that part is executed, then I want to wait `Counter()` as below-

```
        if (A_rray().length!=0){
                           Main_Function(500,A_rray());
                              }
else{console.log('Number = ',A_rray().length)}
Counter();
```

Functions are-

```
function A_rray(){ D=[1,2];return D;}  
function  Counter(){console.log('Done!');}
function  Main_Function(N,A){
    var counter = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        counter++;
        if (counter === A.length) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        console.log(counter, 'iteration')
    }, N)                  }
```

But the problem is, `Counter()` function executes first, then the condition and other parts, this is probably because `setInterval`.

I tried some approaches written on Stack Overflow, but those didn't work since I am a beginner.

Is there a simplistic way to to execute first function   `Main_Function(N,A)` based on `Array()`,then execute  `Counter()` efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the more simpler ways of doing this would be to edit your `MAIN_FUNCTION` so that you call `Counter` from inside there.

```
function MAIN_FUNCTION(N,A) {
  var counter = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        counter++;
        console.log(counter, 'iteration');
        if (counter === A.length) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            Counter();
        }
    }, N);
}
```

And then getting rid of the other `Counter` Call from the execution bit

This will ensure that `Counter` is only run after the last iteration of the `interval`

Few notes:

- Seeing that `Counter` is only logging you could simply replace the call with the log call
- Calling a function `Array` is overwriting a default function of javascript that is the constructor of the `Array` class

Answer (score 1):

You can return a `Promise` which will resolve if `clearInterval` is called from `Main_Function(N,A)`. Therefore, you can wait `Main_Function(N,A)` to finish, and then execute `Counter()` as desired.

```js
(async() => {
  if (Array().length != 0) {
    await Main_Function(500, Array());
  } else {
    console.log('Number = ', Array().length)
  }
  Counter();
})();

function Array() {
  D = [1, 2];
  return D;
}

function Counter() {
  console.log('Done!');
}

function Main_Function(N, A) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    var counter = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      counter++;
      if (counter === A.length) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        resolve();
      }
      console.log(counter, 'iteration');
    }, N);
  });
}
```